# How to store class variable inside a Craft controller

Tags: plugin-development

```
namespace Craft;

class Test_FormsController extends BaseController
{

   protected $allowAnonymous = true;
   public $session_id;

    public function actionApply(){
        $appl_template = "1";
        $this->session_id = 15558145;
        return $this->renderTemplate("apply/step".$appl_template.".html");
    }

    public function actionSaveDataStruct(){
        echo 'session:'.$this->session_id.'<br />';
        exit();
    }
}
```

Hi guys i'm newbie on Craft and my question is:

`acctionApply` loads form which will send to `actionSaveDataStruct`, I set a class variable `$session_id` on `actionApply` but whenever the form submitted and goes to `actionSaveDataStruct`, `$this->session_id` become null again, how do I set variable that will never reset whenever the page load?

Answer (score 2):

In addition to passing the value along through a [cookie](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/10791/57), you could also do it through PHP's session support.

Adding:

```
craft()->httpSession->add('sessionId', '123456');
```

Retrieving:

```
$sessionId = craft()->httpSession->get('sessionId');
```

Deleting:

```
craft()->httpSession->remove('sessionId');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use cookies from craft to store / retrieve and delete the session id. Craft checks if the value isn't tampered with and hashed the value.

Creating a cookie:

```
craft()->userSession->saveCookie('session_id', $this->session_id, $duration);
```

Where duration is in seconds, don't know what happens if you use 0.

For retrieving the cookie value

```
$sessionId = craft()->userSession->getStateCookieValue('sessionId');
```

If you want to delete the cookie in the final step.

```
craft()->userSession->deleteStateCookie('session_id');
```

Good luck!

Comment: If you set `$duration` to 0 (or just don't pass it as a parameter), it's a browser session based cookie and will expire when the browser is closed.

Comment: Also, I'd probably go through HttpRequest's cookie methods instead of UserSessionService's.  The latter deals specifically with the identity cookie that Craft uses when logging in and for session management. See: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/152/cookie-management-in-yii/ and just replace `Yii::app()->request` with `craft()->request`.